# Could FRB be the result of matter-antimatter annihilation?

Tags: gamma-ray-bursts, antimatter

I was listening to a scientific podcast about CPT-symmetry and mirror-universes, and when speaking about matter-antimatter annihilation, they stated that several emissions would occur at this time, notably gamma rays.

So this raised that question to me: I know that FRB (Fast Radio Bursts) are theorized differently today (lifecycle of some stars, etc.) but, could they actually be the result of matter-antimatter annihilation occurring locally (i.e. a bunch of matter colliding another bunch of matter)? After all, matter cohabiting with antimatter has been one theory, but we failed to find evidence of it... unless it is FRB.

Note that this is a newbie question and I'm not convinced of that, but would rather know *why* this cannot be the case (like, "we have solid proof of what FRB are", or "the matter-antimatter emissions would not be the same as the ones in FRBs", etc.).

Comment: Electron + positron annihilation has a distinctive gamma ray signature. At low collision speeds you mostly see 511 keV gammas.